# NGINX downloads PHP file instead of showing

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I'm trying to display index.php and info.php on my NGINX webserver but i cant get it working for some reason, my browser keeps downloading the files instead of displaying them. I tried alot of tutorials but i dont know whats wrong.

OS: Ubuntu 17.10 Server

PHP version: 7.1

cgi.fix_pathinfo is set to 0

www.conf file is default except de cgi.fix_pathinfo

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name nginx1.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this smaller example.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

And double check if your php-fpm is running:

```
sudo systemctl status php7.1-fpm.service
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. For some reason my vhost config was gone after a reboot. I inserted your configuration and it worked! Thank you very much!